# vec_math.yearweek error in R when trying to plot ARIMA forecast

Tags: r, ggplot2

I generated an ARIMA forecast off of my original dataset and I am trying to use ggplot to plot the data. The error that I am getting reads Error: `vec_math.yearweek()` not implemented. How do I correct this so I no longer receive the error.

I am trying to plot the two variables, week and wk_vol.

This is the code that I am running. Also note that I am getting the same error when using autplot

```
forecast %>% ggplot(aes(x= week, y = wk_vol))+geom_line()
```

running the dput function I get the following structure:

```
structure(list(.model = c("arima1", "arima1", "arima1", "arima1", 
"arima1", "arima1", "arima1", "arima1", "arima1", "arima1", "arima1", 
"arima1", "arima1", "arima1", "arima1", "arima1", "arima1", "arima1", 
"arima1", "arima1", "arima1", "arima1", "arima1", "arima1", "arima1", 
"arima1"), week = structure(c(18267L, 18274L, 18281L, 18288L, 
18295L, 18302L, 18309L, 18316L, 18323L, 18330L, 18337L, 18344L, 
18351L, 18358L, 18365L, 18372L, 18379L, 18386L, 18393L, 18400L, 
18407L, 18414L, 18421L, 18428L, 18435L, 18442L), class = c("yearweek", 
"vctrs_vctr")), wk_vol = c(1316.72042466193, 1234.51752709239, 
1175.91778489032, 1332.80903255866, 1484.79281876737, 1365.67061535353, 
1066.94870087541, 1269.16113653454, 1398.27340776577, 1511.32779697918, 
1821.06601904706, 1871.25561580257, 1725.87372040778, 1890.76930241993, 
1636.66080226716, 1775.80441429268, 1403.39449674274, 1303.14521282485, 
1612.00786589938, 1362.70829279138, 1135.30057574297, 1481.73816276555, 
1713.07997455903, 1487.42315637531, 1555.84897647107, 1222.0236771494
), .distribution = structure(list(list(mean = 1316.72042466193, 
    sd = 976.522977836466, .env = <environment>), list(mean = 1234.51752709239, 
    sd = 1381.01203922529, .env = <environment>), list(mean = 1175.91778489032, 
    sd = 1691.38741237122, .env = <environment>), list(mean = 1332.80903255866, 
    sd = 1953.04595567293, .env = <environment>), list(mean = 1484.79281876737, 
    sd = 2183.57176003286, .env = <environment>), list(mean = 1365.67061535353, 
    sd = 2391.98301780251, .env = <environment>), list(mean = 1066.94870087541, 
    sd = 2583.63694889553, .env = <environment>), list(mean = 1269.16113653454, 
    sd = 2762.024078438, .env = <environment>), list(mean = 1398.27340776577, 
    sd = 2929.55707086519, .env = <environment>), list(mean = 1511.32779697918, 
    sd = 3088.01428964329, .env = <environment>), list(mean = 1821.06601904706, 
    sd = 3238.7281260745, .env = <environment>), list(mean = 1871.25561580257, 
    sd = 3382.73373120188, .env = <environment>), list(mean = 1725.87372040778, 
    sd = 3520.85431646865, .env = <environment>), list(mean = 1890.76930241993, 
    sd = 3653.7573454433, .env = <environment>), list(mean = 1636.66080226716, 
    sd = 3781.99290863505, .env = <environment>), list(mean = 1775.80441429268, 
    sd = 3906.0207350385, .env = <environment>), list(mean = 1403.39449674274, 
    sd = 4026.22970086601, .env = <environment>), list(mean = 1303.14521282485, 
    sd = 4142.95223551039, .env = <environment>), list(mean = 1612.00786589938, 
    sd = 4256.47516700209, .env = <environment>), list(mean = 1362.70829279138, 
    sd = 4367.04802685869, .env = <environment>), list(mean = 1135.30057574297, 
    sd = 4474.88950595155, .env = <environment>), list(mean = 1481.73816276555, 
    sd = 4580.19254093758, .env = <environment>), list(mean = 1713.07997455903, 
    sd = 4683.12837039998, .env = <environment>), list(mean = 1487.42315637531, 
    sd = 4783.84980483607, .env = <environment>), list(mean = 1555.84897647107, 
    sd = 4882.49388907094, .env = <environment>), list(mean = 1222.0236771494, 
    sd = 4979.18408962754, .env = <environment>)), class = c("fcdist", 
"list"))), row.names = c(NA, -26L), key = structure(list(.model = "arima1", 
    .rows = structure(list(1:26), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = 1L, class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), index = structure("week", ordered = TRUE), index2 = "week", interval = structure(list(
    year = 0, quarter = 0, month = 0, week = 1, day = 0, hour = 0, 
    minute = 0, second = 0, millisecond = 0, microsecond = 0, 
    nanosecond = 0, unit = 0), .regular = TRUE, class = c("interval", 
"vctrs_rcrd", "vctrs_vctr")), response = list(wk_vol), dist = .distribution, model_cn = ".model", class = c("fbl_ts", 
"tbl_ts", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: It would probably help to mention what package(s) you're using for the forecast or what functions initiate the `yearweek` vctrs-class. Also, I don't think ggplot2 hasn't natively adopted vctrs yet, so it would probably be more convenient to convert the yearweek class to a regular date or datetime class.

Comment: I am using fable, fabletools, feasts, and tsibble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the latest CRAN version of tsibble? It seems your `yearweek()` object is not correctly structured, try re-creating the object with the latest release version of tsibble.

```r
library(tsibble)
library(ggplot2)
tsibble(grp = "A", idx = yearweek(1:10), y = rnorm(10), index = idx, key = grp) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = idx, y = y)) + 
  geom_line()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>